# Switch.EXE not convert the file when runs under IIS Directory

Tags: c#

I am using NCH Switch for audio file conversion. i am using its command line to convert the file but it runs when i run under the port using VS. when i run using virtual directory from IIS it does not convert the file and stuck on process.start().

i use below code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new  System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError=true;
var cmdArguments = "\""+fullExePath+"\" -convert \"" + sourcePath+ "\" -format .wav -outfolder \"" + DestPath+ "\" -hide -overwrite ALWAYS -exit";
startInfo.FileName = string.Concat(exePath,"switch.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = cmdArguments;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow=true;
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Start();
```

Comment: I think it depends on fullexepath value, there may be need to get virtual path

Comment: fullexepath contains full path like C:/Program Files (X86)/SW Vendor/ABC.exe

Comment: Is the task even started, e.g. do you see a `switch.exe` process in the task manager on the IIS machine (make sure that "all users" is checked)?

Comment: no, thats the problem. switch.exe is not start in task manager

Comment: Are you hosting it in your local IIS or some remote server?

Comment: same issue on local & remote server while run under IIS Application